# Selecting new records using values inside previous selected rows in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute, qgis-python-console

I am trying to create a selection. First, I select records which have Null value in "Status" column (`"Status" is NULL"`). Then it starts to be a bit tricky. I want to select all the records which have the same number as selected "Status" records. Is it possible to do it in QGIS?

First, I select null values using `"Status" is NULL` expression.

[image: First step]

Then I need to add something to take ID values and use it to create a new selection.

The final selection should look like that:

[image: Second step]

I am using QGIS 2.16.

Comment: Since you first select `"Status" IS NULL`, what do you mean by "records having the same number"?

Comment: I mean records with the same ID as selected "STATUS" records. So in this case it all with number 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may run this code from the **Python Console** (it works on the active layer):

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
query_1 = '"Status" is NULL'
selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query_1))
selected_ids = [k["ID"] for k in selection]

ids = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    if feat["ID"] in selected_ids:
        ids.append(feat.id())
layer.setSelectedFeatures([l for l in ids])
```

You will obtain the desired output:

[image]